# Fatal error LNK1104 cannot open file MSVCRT.lib with /Qspectre and spectre libs *installed* in Universal Windows C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, uwp

I've installed the Spectre-mitigated C++ libs in Visual Studio 2019 and in my C++ (non-WinRT, pure C) Universal Windows project (which is being used as a native DLL included in a Store app for P/Invoke), I enable the Spectre mitigation option under the Code Generation settings for the project (same as /Qspectre switch).
Despite the libs being installed (see screenshot), I'm still getting the linking error, which contradicts Microsoft documentation. Disabling Spectre mitigation results in the build working fine.
How do I get things working with it enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Note part of this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2019), it mentions:

> There are no versions of Spectre-mitigated libraries for Universal
>   Windows (UWP) apps or components. App-local deployment of such
>   libraries isn't possible.

So for UWP application, you can't enable the Spectre mitigation option.

Comment: Thanks. However, on a system with WDK installed, the VS2019 default is Qspectre enabled for C++ projects regardless of whether they're UWP or not, which makes no sense if it's not supported in the UWP case. Is there a way I can change this without adding an explicit disabling in the vcxproj? Or is this going to be fixed soon?

Comment: I installed the WDK and created a c++ project, it indeed enables the spectre-mitigated. But when I created a c++/cx UWP project, it still disables the spectre-mitigated option. So in this case, it should not apply for UWP.